# Selecting inverted Uvs

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am very new at Blender and was wondering if there is a way to automatically select the inverted UVs, like the option in the UV editor in 3Ds max named "Select Inverted Polygon".

Comment: There's a script, but I can find it.
If you need I could add it in oscurar tools.